# font looks pixalated in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, css

I build that site with dynamic portfolio, now i looked at it in IE8 and for some reason font with sub navigation on the right hand side is getting distorted and have this unwanted white background it looks fine in all the other browsers only IE8 gives me that problem have a look at site and please help.

http://teddington-kitchens.fsdegrees.com/portfolio/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's to do with setting opacity on an element - IE has a long-standing bug with font-rendering using opacity values. I believe it's actually part of the underlying operating system's "ClearType" anti-aliasing. I'm afraid the only way I've gotten around it in the past is to sniff for IE and not use opacity, but then again I'm pretty lazy like that... :)

Here's a [workaround](http://web.archive.org/web/20090416120759/http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/12/ie7_cleartype_dximagetransform.html) you could try - it uses IE's proprietary `filters` attribute if possible, which seems to get around the auto-disabling of ClearType mode.